# In Node js when using Java module fetching Segmentation fault errror

Tags: node.js

```
// test.js

var java = require('java');
var javaLangSystem = java.import('java.lang.System');

javaLangSystem.out.printlnSync('Hello World');

//output 
node test.js
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Update 1 :

Running on AWS EC2 instance.
Ubuntu 14.04.05
node v8.1.4
nodejs v8.1.4
npm 5.0.3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Did you follow the [guide](https://github.com/joeferner/node-java)? Did you install node-java? Did you install java?

Comment: I got no error at all. Be sure you installed Java on your server. And also keep NodeJS up to date.

Comment: I followed steps mention in link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/java
Java version : 1.8 oracle. has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

Env: AWS Ubuntu 14.04.5
Package: node-java
Error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Possible cause: Linux-image version update causing node-java to fail.
https://github.com/joeferner/node-java/issues/399

- Add below line your code

java.options.push('-Xss1280k');